# Problem storing the right value while simulating

Tags: python

So I am simulating different random phone calls according a Poisson distribution. I'm checking every minute if there is a call or not and storing it in a dictionary.

This is an example of how my calls dictionary looks like:

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 2,
 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, ......
```

What I want to do, is if there have been calls that minute (value > 0) to store the time in a class instance. Each dictionary key corresponds to a minute .

Currently, this is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

# initial day and time of simulation
numberOfSimulationDays = 28
currentDay = 1
currentTime = 0

# 2. Timeslots & availability
hours = []
free = []
start_time = 0
end_time = 480
time = start_time
end = end_time

while time <= end:
    hours.append(time)
    free.append(True)
    time += 15

class Slot:
    def __init__(self, slot, available):
        self.slot = slot
        self.available = available

timeSlots = {}
rangeHours = np.size(hours)

for i in range(rangeHours):
    timeSlots[i] = Slot(hours[i],free[i])


# 2. Simualte calls
patient = {}
class Patient:
    def __init__(self, calltime, slot):
        self.calltime = calltime
        self.slot = slot
        self.arrivalTime = slot + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2.5,size=None)
        self.AppointmentWaitingTime = self.arrivalTime - calltime

class Schedule:
    @staticmethod
    def get_number_of_calls_in_minute():
        number_of_calls_in_minute = 
            np.random.poisson(lam=28.345 / (9 * 24), size=None)
        return number_of_calls_in_minute

class SimulationEveryMinute:
    while currentDay <= numberOfSimulationDays:
        calls = {}
        currentTime = 0
        endOfDayTime = 540

        while currentTime < endOfDayTime:

            for i in range(endOfDayTime):
                calls[i] = Schedule.get_number_of_calls_in_minute()

            for call in calls:
                if call == 1:
                    for slot_index, Slot in timeSlots.items():
                        if timeSlots[slot_index].available == True:
                             patient[slot_index] =
                                 Patient(currentTime, Slot.slot)
                             timeSlots[slot_index].available = False
                        currentTime += 1
        currentDay = currentDay + 1

print(SimulationEveryMinute.calls)
print("Number of calls:", sum(SimulationEveryMinute.calls.values()))
print("Number of scheduled patients:", len(patient))
for i in patient:
    print("Calltime:", patient[i].calltime, "Slottime:",
          patient[i].slot, "Appointment waiting time:",
          patient[i].AppointmentWaitingTime)
```

The problem with this is that it just increments currentTime from 1 to 32 (I have 32 timeSlots) instead of storing the minute on which the call has been made.

Example of the output:

```
('Calltime:', 0, 'Slottime:', 0, 'Appointment waiting time:', 0.4138422146210218)
('Calltime:', 1, 'Slottime:', 15, 'Appointment waiting time:', 11.162701908696011)
('Calltime:', 2, 'Slottime:', 30, 'Appointment waiting time:', 27.40165239831842)
('Calltime:', 3, 'Slottime:', 45, 'Appointment waiting time:', 41.696420163160745)
```

Instead, it should give

```
('Calltime:', 2, 'Slottime:', 0, 'Appointment waiting time:', 0.4138422146210218)
('Calltime:', 9, 'Slottime:', 15, 'Appointment waiting time:', 11.162701908696011)
('Calltime:', 9, 'Slottime:', 30, 'Appointment waiting time:', 27.40165239831842)
```

Could anyone help me see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have edited my post, hope this is better.

Comment: Your posted code still does nothing.  It defines one or two classes and quits without doing anything.  Again, see the description of a MCVE.

Comment: I did not want to post all of it, as it is a homework assignment and it should not be public on the internet. However, I have updated it again and you should have enough code to run it.

Comment: Okay; we're almost there.  You do *not* need to post all of it, merely enough to focus on the problem.  About half of your code is involved in generating and processing the dict of Poisson data; this should be replaced with a simple assignment statement and a loop to create patients.  Let's leave that alone for now.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the processing that goes into your output.  The "Calltime" *should* be the integer minute at which the patient originally called -- but your current code simply prints the slot number, lock-stepped with the "Slottime" in 15-minute increments.  Is that correct?

Comment: I am sorry, still new to this and also not that good a programmer to know exactly which parts to leave out and which not, but I'm getting there.  Yes that's right!

Comment: @starlife, I would use a `list(...)` or a `[...]` here, instead of a dict.  You're using discrete incrementing numbers, instead of strings for your keys, which lends itself much more directly to a list. You would be able to define your data from above like so: 
`[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`

Comment: @DavidCulbreth thank you, that is indeed a better way to store my data, but it still does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it appears that this is simply a matter of printing that call time from the `Patient` object, instead of the slot number:

```
print("Calltime:", ceil(patient[i].arrivalTime),
    "Slottime:",patient[i].slot, "Appointment waiting time:",
    patient[i].AppointmentWaitingTime)
```

Second, I don't understand the dict you're using.  If this is simply calls in any given minute, then use a list.  The list index is the minute number:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, ...]
```

You can simplify several of your loops with better logic application and the occasional `enumerate` call -- that's an iterator that steps through both the index and value, such as

```
for slot_num, freq in enumerate(calls):
```

---

I suggest that you simplify your coding somewhat.  For starters, use incremental programming: write a block of code and make sure that the results are exactly what you want.  Don't write more code until you've debugged that one.

Second, do *not* use a class until you know that you require the additional features.  The posted code uses some classes that don't add anything to the simpler code within.

---

Your call generation code runs for every minute of the day, overwriting the original call frequencies.

```
    currentTime = 0

    while currentTime < endOfDayTime:

        # This generates a call frequency for every minute of the day.
        for i in range(endOfDayTime):
            calls[i] = Schedule.get_number_of_calls_in_minute()

        for call in calls:
            if call == 1:    # Should this be call >= 1 ??
                ...
                    currentTime += 1
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to affect my answer.  Also, note that every minute of the day, you regenerate the day's entire call log: you have nested loops that run both `currentTime` and `i` through the range of minutes.  This makes the printed results nearly impossible to reconcile.